# When should you normalise (or not) database tables?

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

I don't really understand when I should normalise and when I shouldn't.  In this specific case, I have a set of businesses, and a set of postcodes.  Each business has a number of postcodes they serve (generally two or three hundred).  For normalisation should I have three tables, like:

```
businesses - id, address, other data etc.
business_postcodes - business_id, postcode_id
postcode - id, postcode
```

or is it okay to just have two tables and put the actual postcode in the `business_postcodes` table?  What are the advantages/disadvantages of doing it either way? Does it depend on how much data I have?  I'm doing this in MySQL if that makes a difference; there will probably be around 4 million entries in the `business_postcodes` table, and some businesses will have a lot of overlap in postcodes served, although equally some will have no overlap at all.

Comment: How large are the postcodes?  5, 9, 10 bytes could be plausible.  You can probably afford to have the postcodes verbatim in the `business_postcodes` table as long as you have the `postcode` table to provide validation that the postcode is valid (so you need an FK from `business_postcodes` to `postcode`).  These days, it is unlikely that the space saving from a 4-byte ID value compared with a 10-byte postcode is going to be enough to matter.

Comment: You didn't describe any reason for the `postcode` table.  It seems like just a multivalued attribute of businesses.

Comment: All the valid postcodes fit in a char(7) field.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler nailed it, I think. You might want to normalize the postcodes out into their own table if there's additional data you want to associated with each postcode like, say, locality name. Then normalization could spare you some duplication and consistency issues. But if you don't expect to have that need in the immediate future, it makes perfect sense for postcode to simply be a column in `businesses_postcodes`.

Comment: Creating a third table will require changes to your application to select, insert (to three tables now), and to update data. If you group the 4 million entries, you can project how much deduplication you can expect with the third table. Is it worth the effort?